# Create new column based on other columns values with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the picture below:

[image]

I want to create a new column as "positive_review_contents" which contains the value from the column "review_contents" and the value is corresponding with column "individual_rate" where it is equal and higher than 4.

For the new column "positive_review_contents", some corresponding rows, where the "individual_rate" is below 4, will be Null so I could assign that Null value to "No Positive"

Please help to advise me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please post your expected output based on the shared input. Also, don't post images. Paste everything as text.

Comment: The output you request is not clear enough. Please post an example

Comment: oh sorry, I will post clearer question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def get_prc(x):
    individual_rate = x["individual_rate"]
    if individual_rate >= 4:
        return x["review_contents"] + " " + str(individual_rate)
    return "Not positive"
 
df["positive_review_contents"] = df[["individual_rate", "review_contents"]].apply(get_prc, axis = 1)
```

The code above applies the function `get_prc` row-wise.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!
I just had to remove the "+ " " + str(individual_rate)" because I actually don't need the rate with it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this and let me know if it works fine?

```
df["positive_review_contents"] = df["individual_rate"].apply(lambda x: (review_contents+individual_rate) if x >= 4 else 'No Positive Review')
```